# Using the last 4 digits of a phone number

Tags: combinatorics

Using the last 4 digits of a phone number , how many times will the first three digits add up to the final digit?

Comment: Could you share some of your thoughts?

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large{12 \choose 9} = 220}$.

Comment: How many times?  Really depends on how many phone numbers you look at.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You're trying to find how many times the first three of the digits add together to produce a single-digit number. That is, if the number is "abcdefgh", then $e+f+g<10$.

As Felix Marin has provided the actual answer, I'll explain how that works.

Treat it like a partitioning issue. Consider a set of nine identical objects in a row:

ooooooooo

Now, you insert three lines between these objects, to separate them into groups. For instance,

oo|oooo|o|oo

Now, this can be read as 2,4,1,2. In which case, we only care about the first three numbers, 241. This is one possible set of three digits. Any combination with a sum of less than nine are possible, including...

|||ooooooooo => 000

ooooooooo||| => 900

o|ooooooo|o| => 171

ooo||oooo|oo => 304

The general form for this becomes

xxxxxxxxxxxx <- 12 spots, amongst which you can place nine objects. The remaining three spots will have lines. Hence, $\binom{12}9$.

Comment: Fine. It's always better a "counting solution".

Answer (score 0):

If the final digit is 4, then you need $a+b+c=4$, where $a,b,c$ are each nonnegative integers.  There are $\left(\!{3\choose 4}\!\right)={6\choose 4}=15$ such integers.

If the final digit is 0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9, I leave those to you.

Comment: That's the long way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
?
&
=
\sum_{n_{1} = 0}^{9}\sum_{n_{2} = 0}^{9}\sum_{n_{3} = 0}^{9}\sum_{n_{4} = 0}^{9}
\delta_{n_{1} + n_{2} + n_{3}, n_{4}}
=
\sum_{n_{1} = 0}^{9}\sum_{n_{2} = 0}^{9}\sum_{n_{3} = 0}^{9}\sum_{n_{4} = 0}^{9}
\oint_{\left\vert z \right\vert = 1^{-}}
{{\rm d}z \over 2\pi{\rm i}}\,{1 \over z^{-n_{1} - n_{2} - n_{3} + n_{4} + 1}}
\\[3mm]&=
\oint_{\left\vert z \right\vert = 1^{-}}{{\rm d}z \over 2\pi{\rm i}}\,
{1 \over z}\,
\left(\sum_{n = 0}^{9}z^{n}\right)^{3}\sum_{n_{4} = 0}^{9}{1 \over z^{n_{4}}}
=
\oint_{\left\vert z \right\vert = 1^{-}}{{\rm d}z \over 2\pi{\rm i}}\,
{1 \over z}\,
\left(1 - z^{10} \over 1 - z\right)^{3}\,{1 - z^{-10} \over 1 - z^{-1}}
\\[3mm]&=
\oint_{\left\vert z \right\vert = 1^{-}}{{\rm d}z \over 2\pi{\rm i}}\,
{1 \over z^{10}}\,
\left(1 - z^{10}\right)^{4}\left(1 - z\right)^{-4}
\\[3mm]&=
\oint_{\left\vert z \right\vert = 1^{-}}{{\rm d}z \over 2\pi{\rm i}}\,
{1 \over z^{10}}\,
\sum_{n_{1} = 0}^{4}{4 \choose n_{1}}\left(-1\right)^{n_{1}}z^{10n_{1}}
\sum_{n_{2} = 0}^{\infty}{n_{2} + 3 \choose n_{2}}z^{n_{2}}
\\[3mm]&=
\oint_{\left\vert z \right\vert = 1^{-}}{{\rm d}z \over 2\pi{\rm i}}\,
{1 \over z^{10}}\,
\sum_{n_{1} = 0}^{4}{4 \choose n_{1}}\left(-1\right)^{n_{1}}z^{10n_{1}}
\sum_{n_{2} = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{n - 10n_{1} + 3 \choose n - 10n_{1}}z^{n - 10n_{1}}\,
\delta_{n, 10n_{1} + n_{2}}
\\[3mm]&=
\oint_{\left\vert z \right\vert = 1^{-}}{{\rm d}z \over 2\pi{\rm i}}\,
{1 \over z^{10}}\,\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{n}
\sum_{n_{1} = 0}^{4}\left(-1\right)^{n_{1}}{4 \choose n_{1}}
{n - 10n_{1} + 3 \choose n - 10n_{1}}
\sum_{n_{2} = 0}^{\infty}\delta_{n_{2},n - 10n_{1}}
\\[3mm]&=
\oint_{\left\vert z \right\vert = 1^{-}}{{\rm d}z \over 2\pi{\rm i}}\,
{1 \over z^{10}}\,\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{n}
\sum_{n_{1} = 0 \atop {\vphantom{\LARGE A}n -10n_{1} \geq 0}}^{4}
\left(-1\right)^{n_{1}}{4 \choose n_{1}}
{n - 10n_{1} + 3 \choose n - 10n_{1}}
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{n_{1} = 0 \atop {\vphantom{\LARGE A}9 -10n_{1} \geq 0}}^{4}
\left(-1\right)^{n_{1}}{4 \choose n_{1}}
{12 - 10n_{1} \choose 9 - 10n_{1}}
=
{12 \choose 9}
=
{12\times 11\times 10 \over 3 \times 2}
=
2\times 11\times 10
=
\color{#ff0000}{\Large 220}
\end{align}

We checked numerically the result with a $\tt C\!+\!\!+$ script ( see below ).

```
/* telf34_0.cc 10-oct-2013
http://math.stackexchange.com/users/85343/felix-marin
*/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char uchar;
const uchar TEN=uchar(10);

int main()
{
 uchar n1,n2,n3,n4;
 size_t total=0;

 for ( n1=0 ; n1<TEN ; ++n1 ) {
     for ( n2=0 ; n2<TEN ; ++n2 ) {
         for ( n3=0 ; n3<TEN ; ++n3 ) {
             for ( n4=0 ; n4<TEN ; ++n4 ) {
                 if ( (n1 + n2 + n3)==n4 ) ++total;
             }
         }
     }

 } 

 cout<<"Total = "<<total<<endl;

 return 0;
}
```

There are
$\displaystyle{{n + 2 \choose n}
=
{\left(n + 1\right)\left(n + 2\right) \over 2}}$ combinations of threee digits which add to $\displaystyle{n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 9}$.

Comment: ... Hey, I have to work out what 2+3 is. Can you find me a contour integral involving error functions to determine the value? :P

Comment: @GlenO I'm working on it.